# Declaring a generic list method - how does this work?

Tags: list, class, c#-4.0, generics, methods

Im studying C# and came across a piece of code that Im quite confused about

```
 private static List<Customer> CreateCustomerList()
 List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>{new Customer{FirstName="Orlando"}
 };
 return customers;
 }
```

Im confused with the line where it starts

```
private static List<Customer> CreateCustomerList()....
```

Im used to seeing for example

```
private static class CreateCustomerList()....
```

Why would I need to use List instead of declaring the method as a class?

Comment: Can you explain little more.. You have CreateCustomerList() which will return List of Customers. I didn't get you what is the confusion here.

Comment: Your question is not totaly clear. I changed my answer a bit. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line where you are confuses is the method signature and the return type of the method is  of List, means that method will return the list of customers entity.

Thaanks